# How to disable accented characters in keyboard? [Win 10/11]

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11

When I use the shortcuts which involve ctrl + alt, the accented characters like l̥śḍṅḥ gets displayed instead of triggering the shortcut.

For example,

```
ctrl + alt + l => l̥
ctrl + alt + a => ā
```

Can anyone please let me know how to disable these accented characters completely?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you actually pressing both Ctrl & Alt on the left side of the keyboard, or AltGr on the right?

Comment: I'm pressing ctrl and alt on the left.

Answer (score 0):

selecting the language to English US helped me to get rid of special characters.
I chose English India as the default.